# Does java object class has any variables inside it apart from methods

Tags: java, variables, object

Actually till date What I know about java object class is it has methods like we have clone(), toString() but somebody told me it contains variables also. So what are those variables. Went through google. Does anybody know anything which variable it contains.

Comment: You can look at the source code of `java.lang.Object` yourself, you can find it in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: Jersper is right. Besides you can also have a look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java

Comment: @Jesper Actually yesterday I was interviewed with very established software compnay and the questions Does object class contain any varibales and if yes what are the names of those variables?

Comment: Really? That must be one of the worst job interview questions I've ever heard...

Comment: Java class can't contain variable. In Java terminology class containts fields (object properties) and methods (object behavior)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contain any fields.  You should be able to open the source code from your Java installation and confirm this for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Java Object doesn't have any fields. You can see the source yourself to validate.

But yes whenever an object is created , a monitor is also created alongside to handle the locking on that object. Similarly jvm keeps a track of number of threads requesting lock on the object, these variable are not part of java object, but associated. I guess the interviewer was hinting at those.

[Read this for More on Monitor](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch2.html)